# UIImageView not reshaping properly

Tags: swift, ios9

Here's the code:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


    profilePic.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7, 40, 40)
    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.width/2
    profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true

    contentView.addSubview(profilePic)
}
```

I've always used this code to make an image circular, but now it only becomes a rectangle with rounded corner, how can I solve this?

[edit] This method has worked for me every time I needed, but now that I do this in a separate class for the cell of a UITableView, it doesn't give the circular shape to the image!

Comment: use `image.clipsToBounds = true` and try

Comment: Does not work @EICaptain

Comment: Did you set  masksToBounds to false and use clipsToBounds

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```
self.img.layer.cornerRadius = self.img.frame.size.width / 2
self.img.clipsToBounds = true
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I've tried, but it's not working anyway,

Comment: @dpstart It is working in my app ..

Comment: It worked all the times on my app, but this time, I have no idea why, it doesn't.

Comment: Make sure you add a description to your answers. welcome to Stack Overflow recommended reading [answer]

Answer (score 0):

It worked if i have given this logic in viewDidLoad

```
    testingImageView.layer.cornerRadius = testingImageView.frame.width/2
    testingImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    testingImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(testingImageView)
```

Comment: I know, this method as worked for me all over the app, but now, I don't way, it doesn't.